# Selection section of file using sed based on predefined header

Tags: regex, linux, sed, text-processing

This expression `sed -n '/statistics:/,/^  [^ ]/ p'` selects the following section

```
  Channel statistics:
    Red:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 114.237 (0.447987)
      standard deviation: 115.1 (0.451372)
      kurtosis: -1.92845
      skewness: 0.0962143
    Green:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 113.318 (0.444384)
      standard deviation: 113.041 (0.443298)
      kurtosis: -1.94057
      skewness: 0.0648024
    Blue:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 111.01 (0.435332)
      standard deviation: 110.498 (0.433324)
      kurtosis: -1.92769
      skewness: 0.0747213
  Image statistics:
```

From the following file:

```
Image: /tmp/magick-XXpWFUXl
  Base filename: -
  Format: MIFF (Magick Image File Format)
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 480x360+0+0
  Resolution: 72x72
  Print size: 6.66667x5
  Units: Undefined
  Type: TrueColor
  Base type: TrueColor
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: RGB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Red:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 114.237 (0.447987)
      standard deviation: 115.1 (0.451372)
      kurtosis: -1.92845
      skewness: 0.0962143
    Green:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 113.318 (0.444384)
      standard deviation: 113.041 (0.443298)
      kurtosis: -1.94057
      skewness: 0.0648024
    Blue:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 111.01 (0.435332)
      standard deviation: 110.498 (0.433324)
      kurtosis: -1.92769
      skewness: 0.0747213
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 84.6411 (0.331926)
      standard deviation: 109.309 (0.428662)
      kurtosis: -1.6052
      skewness: 0.582669
  Rendering intent: Undefined
  Interlace: None
  Background color: white
  Border color: rgb(223,223,223)
  Matte color: grey74
  Transparent color: black
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 480x360+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: Zip
  Orientation: Undefined
  Properties:
    date:create: 2011-12-07T12:33:31+02:00
    date:modify: 2011-12-07T12:33:31+02:00
    signature: f2adc51db916151ddcc5b206a8921eec0234efa1eeb7484c0046506b749bc392
  Artifacts:
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 179KB
  Number pixels: 173KB
  Pixels per second: 0b
  User time: 0.000u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.000
  Version: ImageMagick 6.6.0-4 2011-06-15 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

- How and why does it work?
- What is the sed format ?
- Why it selects the `Channel statistics:` section but not the `Image statistics:` ?

The source of the expression is taken from the following page http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compare/

Answer (score 1):

> **Your expression:** `sed -n '/statistics:/,/^ [^ ]/ p'`

#### How and why does it work?

`sed` in it's natural form follows the syntax `sed 's/substitution/replacement/[g]'` where `s` is for **substitution** and an optional `g` at the end for **global replacement** (if substitution text is found more than once in a line.

But `sed` can do much more. It has the ability to restrict the operation to certain lines. You can do that by -

```
 1. Specifying a line by its number. 
 2. Specifying a range of lines by number.
 3. All lines containing a pattern.
 4. All lines from the beginning of a file to a regular expression
 5. All lines from a regular expression to the end of the file.
 6. All lines between two regular expressions.
```

#### What is the sed format ?

Your `sed format` takes the **last form**. It starts performing it's magic from the line that contains `statistics:` to the line that contains exactly two spaces from the beginning of the line i.e `__[^_]` where `_` is the space. i.e

```
sed -n '/statistics:/,/^ [^ ]/ p'
   |   ||           | |      | |
    ---  -----------   ------  V
     |        |           |    Since we suppressed
 Suppress This is     This is  the output, we need
  output   your         your   to invoke print
           start        end
           range       range
```

#### Why it selects the `Channel statistics:` section but not the `Image statistics:`?

In your original text lines after `Image Statistics:` are indented and have more than 2 spaces from the beginning of the line as a result they are not displayed. If you want to include `Image Statistics:` you can modify your `Address End Range` to be like this -

```
sed -n '/statistics:/,/^  Ren.*/p'
```

**`Why -n and p?:`**`sed` in it's natural form prints everything. Each line is put in the `pattern space` upon which all actions are performed on it and then the line is printed with a new line. The action over here is `p` which means entire text will be printed and the lines that matches the `sed's` range will be printed twice. To prevent this we invoke the `-n`. The `-n` option will not print anything unless an explicit request to `print` is found.

Answer (score 0):

> **How and why does it work?**

see below

> **What is the sed format ?**

```
format is sed address1, address2
```

**> Why it selects the Channel statistics: section but not the Image statistics: ?**

first, I would say that the sed line in your question is not exactly the same as the line in your link. it should be `sed -n '/statistics:/,/^(two spaces)[^ ]/ p'`

see this example:

```
kent$  cat file1
x_1
 1
 2
 3
 o
x_2
 4
 5
 6

kent$  sed -n '/x/,/^[^ ]/p' file1
x_1
 1
 2
 3
 o
x_2
```

I think this would be quite similar as your file.

what sed does?

> 1 find out the 1st match of address1, which is /x/, so x_1 was found
>   and accepted.
>
> 2 then searching the address2, /^[^ ]/ if not match, print. this regex
>   means, the line not starts with space.
>
> 3 x_2 starts with x, not space, so match address2, print.
>
> after x_2, there is no more line matching address1 /x/, so x_2 should
>   be the last line

your image file example is the same, only difference is address2 in your case is  line starting with **two** spaces.

just my 2 cents. hope helpful.